# Oracle: Inheritance in triggers

Tags: oracle, inheritance, plsql, triggers

I'm working with two objects `Paper` and `Internal_Paper`. `Internal_Paper` inherits from `Paper` and has one additional attribute.

I've only one table to insert both objects `Paper_Table`.

The thing is I've a trigger and I want to access the `:new` and `:old` values of exclisive attributes of `Internal_Paper` objects.

Does anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the definitions of PAPER, INTERNAL_PAPER, PAPER_TABLE, and the trigger in question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

:new and :old values are used by triggers for one specific task. When you update a row, :old returns the old values in the table, :new returns the update-Values.

Paper-Objects have the same columns as Internal_Paper-Objects, but the values of the Internal_Paper-exclusive Attributes are null for Paper-Objects.

So far I don't get your problem - what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to get the :old values from an Internal_Paper object saved into Paper_Table.

Comment: @Sven If this is a request for clarification then please add it as a comment on the question, not as an answer. Thanks